# Google Apps script: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps script to set up a spreadsheet merge to a from letter that will be emailed.  I copied a similar script and added my info. 
Everytime I try to save it I get the "We're sorry a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

```
//  dixie@yellowdogknitting.com
//  Job Offer Letter

//  Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "1Y5ohbBWPeLSvNijge6I3ueQpulFzeZTky7853sKGSj8";
var docName = "HR_2_Job_Offer_form_letter";

//  When Form Gets Submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {

//  Get information from form and set our variables

var email_address = e.values[10];
var date = e.values[1];
var first_name = e.values[2];
var last_name = e.values[3];
var job_title = e.values[11];
var status = e.values[13];
var hourly_wage = e.values[14];
var start_date = e.values[15];

//  Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the doc's id
var copyId = DocList.getFileById(docTemplate)
        .makeCopy(docName+' for '+first_name last_name)
        .getId();

//  Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

//  Get the document's body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

//  Replace place holder keys, in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyTodaysDate', date);
copyBody.replaceText('keyFirstName', first_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyLastName', last_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyJobTitle', job_title);
copyBody.replaceText('keyStatus', status);
copyBody.replaceText('keyHourlyWage', hourly_wage);
copyBody.replaceText('keyStartDate', start_date);

//  Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

//  Convert document to PDF
var pdf = DocList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf")'

//  Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Job Offer";
var body = "Here is the Job Offer for " + first_name last_name + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

//  Delete temp file
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Yea, if you could tell the actual language it would be a lot more easier to help!

Comment: I assume OP meant javascript, so I've changed the tag.

Comment: What is MailApp? Look at the server error logs and see what your problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804649/google-apps-script-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-please-wait-a-bit-and)

Answer (score 2):

This happens when there's some kind of Javascript error thrown behind the scenes.

In order to work out which line has the error, put a breakpoint at the first line of code (you do this by clicking just to the left of the line number.)

Then step through the code and see when the `server error` pops up. Then we can help you work out what's wrong with that particular line.