# Trying to access Gsheet webapp from Python 3.7 using service account

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, google-apps-script

[image: Code is not erroring according to logs][Previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142762/correct-setup-for-accessing-a-gsheet-published-as-a-webapp-via-a-service-account/60142877?noredirect=1#comment106376959_60142877)

Config

- Python 3.7
- google-auth 1.11.0
- google-auth-oauthlib 0.4.1
- Google Service Account credentials
- GSheet shared with ServiceAccount
- GSheet exposed as Webapp
- Gsheet has a doGet method which reads a sheet and converts to CSV and returns it
- Works fine when you hit it directly in the browser
- Doesnt work when using python

Can see the call from python hitting the webapp - can see the webapp processing. Getting a response returned to the client which states -

```
    b'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" 
    href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Error</title><style 
    type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font- 
   family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 
    25px;}</style></head><body style="margin:20px"><div><img alt="Google Apps Script" 
    src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png"></div><div style="text- 
   align:center;font-family:monospace;margin:50px auto 0;max-width:600px">We&#39;re sorry, a 
    server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.</div></body></html>'
```

No errors in logs.

Python code doing the work:-

```
from __future__ import print_function
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.urllib3 import AuthorizedHttp

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
'service_account.json', scopes=SCOPES)


def main():
try:
    authed_http = AuthorizedHttp(credentials)

    response = authed_http.request(
        'GET', "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzmr5-g2ZIlsGFL5SDYdCYEKmhyqH_- 
QcAhFeBnfN0_D291kRA/exec")

    print(response._body)
except BaseException as err_base2:
    print(err_base2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

- [Example Sheet with Code](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1952TvGRYAy-fGAsaB-EnYlXwrurc-4UDwM-k5f7swGs/edit#gid=693007221)
- [WebAppLink](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzmr5-g2ZIlsGFL5SDYdCYEKmhyqH_-QcAhFeBnfN0_D291kRA/exec)
- [Following Guidance From Here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

Is this approach supported. Feel like i'm missing something obvious.

Service Account Role Permissions to GSheet Project
[image: Service Account Role Permissions to GSheet Project]

Service Account Permissions to GSheet
[image]

Put some logging into the requests but it doesnt tell us anymore.
    DEBUG:google.auth.transport.urllib3:Making request: POST 
    https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
    DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 
    oauth2.googleapis.com:443
    DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST 
    /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
    DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 
    script.google.com:443
    DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://script.google.com:443 "GET 
    /macros/s/AKfycbzmr5-g2ZIlsGFL5SDYdCYEKmhyqH_-QcAhFeBnfN0_D291kRA/exec 
    HTTP/1.1" 500 None

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps script: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553828/google-apps-script-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-please-wait-a-bit-and)

Comment: Struggling to find where the error is - wrappped most things with try catch. Added a picture showing the log outputs. Will keep looking.

Comment: When I tested your shared Spreadsheet and scripts of Google Apps Script and python, I could confirm that no error occurs, and the CSV values are returned. So can I ask you about your situation? 1. About `GSheet shared with ServiceAccount`, did you share both the Spreadsheet and GAS project of container-bound script? 2. Can I ask you about the settings for deploying Web Apps?

Comment: Have you considered using the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) to get the data in your spreadsheet as in [these examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_a_single_range) ?

Comment: @taniake - updated 2 images in the question showing the service account permissions on the project and to the gsheet

Comment: @albertovielma - yes thanks - i have utilised pyspread in a lambda function to get at the data via the sheets API. I'm not blocked in terms of a way forward but I would like to understand why this isn't working when hitting the webapp URL directly from python when it does when hitting it as a user in the browser.

Comment: @Tanaike - added some logging output

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. In your situation, your Web Apps is put to the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, in this case, it is required to share not only the Spreadsheet, but also the the container-bound script with the service account. How about this?

Comment: How do I do that over and above what I have done already? The service user has access to the sheet and when i look at the code and share that the permissions are the same. it also has access to the project via Editor role.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. When I could replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same error you were having:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try
>   again.

Then I used [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority), which allows the [service account](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html?highlight=from_service_account_file) to impersonate any user in your [G Suite domain](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_ie). You have to have a G Suite Account to be able to use domain wide-delegation as the docs say:

> If you have a G Suite domain—if you use G Suite, for example—an
>   administrator of the G Suite domain can authorize an application to
>   access user data on behalf of users in the G Suite domain.

So now, why do you need to impersonate an user(a real person)? it's due to the fact a service account is a bot(not a real person) that is used to server-to-server interactions making possible your app calls Google APIs and although the service account has a parameter called `client_email`, which has a structure like `name@project-randomnumber.iam.gserviceaccount.com` it's not a real email that belongs to a real person (kind of confusing I know).

If you check the [Deploying a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) in the 4th step states:

> Under Execute the app as, select whose authorization the app should
>   run with: your account (the developer's) or the account of the user
>   who visits the app (see permissions).

Therefore, you can't use the URL provided by the "Deploy as web app".  To implement domain-wide delegation in your code, you can do it like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.urllib3 import AuthorizedHttp

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service_account.json'
# The user we want to "impersonate"
USER_EMAIL = "name@domain"

def main():
    try:
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
        delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)
        authed_http = AuthorizedHttp(delegated_credentials)
        response = authed_http.request('GET', "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<your-id>/exec")
        print(response._body)
    except BaseException as err_base2:
        print(err_base2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: That sounds like a great answer. I wont be able to implement domain wide delegation here BUT I should be able to give it my individual account which is the owner of the gsheet and see success? Do you agree?

Comment: do you mean like giving to the service account your individual account like "myaccount@gmail.com" to impersonate it? if it's that what you mean, then it will not work because the ```gmail.com``` domain is not a [G Suite domain](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6069226?hl=en)

Comment: no - sorry i wasnt clear. the service account has been provisioned within my work domain. I have an individual account also within the same domain. Could i use this without turning on domain wide delegation? I will test later on but wanted your view on it.

Comment: I updated my answer. If your work domain is not a G Suite domain, then you will not be able to use domain-wide delegation. I hope this can help